# find and replace a specific character unauthorized

Tags: c#

I have a list of characters allowed and I need a function c# which we can check if a text contains a characters no allowed and if we find a character unauthorized we replace with a  carriage return (`\r` or `\n`).

For example:

```
String ListCharactersAllowed = "¥ó;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789}{ ";
String input = @"thîs is @ string text";
```

The result will be like this:

```
String value="th"+((char)13)+"s is "+((char)13)+" string text"
```

Comment: "sorry for my bad english" no problem, but i'm really missing your approach.

Comment: Try searching first. Keyword you're looking for is "whitelist", so use search queries like "C# string replace whitelist". If you did search and did try something but that didn't work, show so in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this LINQ approach:

```
var newCharacters = input.Select(c => ListCharactersAllowed.Contains(c) ? c : (char)13);
String result = String.Concat(newCharacters);
```

If you can't use LINQ use following `StringBuilder` approach which is even more efficient:

```
var newString = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
foreach (char c in input)
    newString.Append(ListCharactersAllowed.IndexOf(c) >= 0 ? c : (char)13);
String result = newString.ToString();
```

Instead of `ListCharactersAllowed.IndexOf(c) >= 0` you could also use `ListCharactersAllowed.Contains(c.ToString())` to avoid the (not avialable) `Enumerable.Contains` call. The former is a little bit more efficient.

Comment: i use the framework 3 i can't execute your code in my case

Comment: this code also i can't execute it , i don't use the framework 4

Comment: @Aimar: sorry, forgotten that `string.Contains(char)` also uses the `Enumerable` extension method. Changed it to [`string.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.80).aspx) which works even on .NET 2.0.

Comment: thanks you very match mister @Tim :)

Comment: i want the same function but for java script

Comment: @Aimar: then ask the question ;)